# How can I achieve a scrollable circular text effect similar to http://thisiskiosk.com/

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you take a look at [KIOSK WEBSITE HERE](http://thisiskiosk.com/) they have the 'WE ARE OPEN" circular type in javascript (I know how to do that) but what I don't know is how to achieve that when scrolling. Like how does the text move when scrolling up or down. How do you get that in HTML/CSS/JS ?

View the code I worked on [here https://codepen.io/noel_emmanuel/pen/WJxRZW](https://codepen.io/noel_emmanuel/pen/WJxRZW)

HTML:

```
<!--just a container used to position in the page-->
<div class="container">
  <!--the holders/targets for the text, reuse as desired-->
  <div class="circTxt" id="test"></div>
</div>

<!--I told you it was simple! :)-->
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #111;
}

.container {
  /*centers in the container*/
  text-align: center;
}

div.circTxt {
  /*allows for centering*/
  display: inline-block;
  /*adjust as needed*/
  margin-bottom: 128px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```

JS:

```
function circularText(txt, radius, classIndex) {
  txt = txt.split(""),
    classIndex = document.getElementsByClassName("circTxt")[classIndex];

  var deg = 360 / txt.length,
    origin = 0;

  txt.forEach((ea) => {
    ea = `<p style='height:${radius}px;position:absolute;transform:rotate(${origin}deg);transform-origin:0 100%'>${ea}</p>`;
    classIndex.innerHTML += ea;
    origin += deg;
  });
}

circularText("WE ARE OPEN", 100, 0);
```

OPEN FOR SUGGESTIONS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rotate this on a scroll event. This simply rotates the `div` depending on how far from the top of the page you have scrolled.

I added a `height` and `width` to the text, as well as positioned it `fixed` to see the effect.

```js
function circularText(txt, radius, classIndex) {
  txt = txt.split(""),
    classIndex = document.getElementsByClassName("circTxt")[classIndex];

  var deg = 360 / txt.length,
    origin = 0;

  txt.forEach((ea) => {
    ea = `<p style='height:${radius}px;position:absolute;transform:rotate(${origin}deg);transform-origin:0 100%'>${ea}</p>`;
    classIndex.innerHTML += ea;
    origin += deg;
  });
}

circularText("WE ARE OPEN", 100, 0);


$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(e){
  rotateText();
 });

 function rotateText(){
  var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('div.circTxt').css('transform','rotate('+scrolled+'deg)');
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #111;
}

.container {
  /*centers in the container*/
  text-align: center;
  
  height: 4000px;
}

div.circTxt {
  /*allows for centering*/
  display: inline-block;
  /*adjust as needed*/
  margin-bottom: 128px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  
  position: fixed;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform-origin: 0% 59%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--just a container used to position in the page-->
<div class="container">
  <!--the holders/targets for the text, reuse as desired-->
  <div class="circTxt" id="test"></div>
</div>

<!--I told you it was simple! :)-->
```